# Get SQL statements of Dev express XPO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, devexpress

I'm new to DevExpress Xpo and can't find a way to get the executed sql statement programmatically for example when I execute session.save(MyClass) ,would be awesome if anyone can help me
Ps. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Microsoft SQL

Comment: I don't know much about devexpress but using sql-server you can use the profiler to track the queries that come in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [XPO Profiler](https://docs.devexpress.com/XpoProfiler/10646/xpo-profiler) to see the generated query statements.

If you are trying to access this information at runtime, you can add a trace listener as described here: [How to log the SQL queries made by XPO](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2572/how-to-log-the-sql-queries-made-by-xpo)

Comment: Nice thank you I will give it a try